# Sum and product of integral elements using resultants

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Update: I know that this question (and similar questions) have been asked before, and I know the non-constructive ways of showing that integral elements are closed under addition and multiplication. I am simply interested in the specific question whether the resultant polynomial $Res_{Z}(f(Z),g(X-Z))$ is necessarily monic when $f$ and $g$ are monic. The rest of the question merely provides context.

Let $A \subseteq B$ be a commutative rings with unity. I want to prove that the sum and product of elements of $B$ that are integral over $A$ are also integral over $A$. That is, for $\alpha,\beta \in B$ with monic minimal polynomials $f(X),g(X) \in A[X]$, I want the minimal polynomials for $\alpha+\beta$ and  $\alpha \beta$.

Now this is similar to the problem of proving that sum and product of algebraic elements in an extension field are algebraic. While there are non-constructive proofs, I am interested in the construction of the polynomial using resultants. In short, if $K \subseteq F$, and $\alpha, \beta \in F$ have minimal polynomials $f(X)g(X) \in K[X]$, then the minimal polynomial of $\alpha+\beta$ is $Res_{Z}(f(Z),g(X-Z)) \in K[X]$ and a similar argument works for products too.

My question now is: will the same approach work for integral elements? Essentially, will the resultant of $f(Z)$ and $g(X-Z)$  interpreted as polynomials over $Z$ with coefficients in $A[X]$, be monic in $X$ when $f$ and $g$ are monic?

Comment: Yes (well, $\pm$ monic, since you have a minus in front of the $Z$). But it won't necessarily be the *minimal* polynomial; just a polynomial annihilating $\alpha+\beta$.

Comment: Is there a way of seeing that from the expression for the Sylvester matrix? I mean, I can intuitively infer that the leading coefficient has to be $1$, but am unable to rigorously prove that.